# Ordered inserts to stl::map faster?

Tags: c++, stl, containers

As the `stl::map` is an ordered map, will it be quicker to insert a sorted data-set? Specially if we consider a large data-set?

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: I think it depends on the specific implementation. `map` usually uses some kind of a tree structure - red-black tree or AVL tree or some such. Inserting a sorted sequence will still trigger re-balance every so often, and that's about the only thing that affects insertion performance. That said, there might be some magic sequences that do not trigger re-balance or trigger them less often. Not necessarily sorted sequences.

Comment: @WhiZTiM: second rule of performance, "never rely on the results measured on just a single machine".

Comment: There is hint in std:::map::insert (which should be std::map::end() in this case),  making insertions amortized constant.

Comment: @DieterLücking Good catch.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, having sorted data.

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> data { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::map<int, int> result;
    // From: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert
    // Amortized constant if the insertion happens in the position just before
    // the hint, logarithmic in the size of the container otherwise.
    for(auto i : data)
        result.insert(result.end(), { i, i} );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's true. From the perspective of big O, inserting N elements one by one is O(N*logN), in comparison, building a map(usually some kind of balanced binary tree) only requires O(N).

You can also take GCC's libstdc++ implementation as a reference.
[gcc/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/stl_map.h](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_map.h#L219)